# Switch user after login in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to run various ansible tasks as root, but due to security restrictions I can only do this by running the command "super su-root" and typing in the password. No sudo allowed. Is it possible to switch user after login like this?

Comment: What is your ansible version?

Comment: Building from source, so latest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

```
Directives

These can be set from play to task level, but are overriden by connection variables as they can be host specific.

become
set to ‘true’/’yes’ to activate privilege escalation.

become_user
set to user with desired privileges, the user you ‘become’, NOT the user you login as. Does NOT imply become: yes, to allow it to be set at host level.

become_method
at play or task level overrides the default method set in ansible.cfg, set to ‘sudo’/’su’/’pbrun’/’pfexec’/’doas’

Connection variables
Each allows you to set an option per group and/or host, these are normally defined in inventory but can be used as normal variables.

ansible_become
equivalent of the become directive, decides if privilege escalation is used or not.

ansible_become_method
allows to set privilege escalation method

ansible_become_user
allows to set the user you become through privilege escalation, does not imply ansible_become: True

ansible_become_pass
allows you to set the privilege escalation password
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html

Comment: Become does not work afaik, since that requires some form of sudo (that is, run command as another user, but don't switch user). I need to actually switch to root before any other task using the "super su-root" command.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible has been transitioning from using `sudo` to [the `become` generic privilege escalation method](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) precisely to support usecases like this.

You will probably need to implement [another `become_method`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/4b0aa1214ca989c71bb87f7a805b1e3673faefa9/lib/ansible/playbook/play_context.py#L474-L534) for your `super` command, or ask the Ansible team to do that for you.

Comment: I don't think `become` will work here.  From your link: "privilege escalation method to use (default=sudo), valid choices: [ sudo | su | pbrun | pfexec | doas ]".  It doesn't appear that one can set an arbitrary command for this.

Comment: Right, I'm suggesting OP has to implement support for their command into ansible itself.  Each implementation seems to be only a few fairly simple lines, and they're already building ansible from source, so while it's obviously not an ideal solution, it may be the easiest to deal with their situation.

Comment: This is already possible by using `become_exe` (which is an undocumented feature), but that doesn't solve the problem because I cannot use the become paradigm at all. The command I have will switch users, not run command as another user.